# Entity Framework with SQL Service Broker

Tags: entity-framework, service-broker

I want to know how /if it is possible to use SQL Service Broker in EF4.x or EF5?

Scenario:
Say, I have a list of products, I don't want to load that from db everytime a customer visits the page. Surely I can cache the page, but if product manager adds a new product, it won't show up immediately, not until the cache has expired or the query param has changed.

Solution:
in SQL we can Enable_Broker and in the web app start link up the SqlDependency. SQL will send notifications to our web app. Therefore, we have a smart 'caching' system.
It would all make sense if we can use that smart cache. We don't need to visit SQL db 1,000 times when there are 1,000 customers clicking that page. But once there is a change in db, 1st customer visiting the page at the time will see the reflection. We get the best of both worlds.

Issue:
Entity Framework is not exposing this ability. Or I am not aware of it? Since SQL 2005 and ASP.NET 2.0 has already got this ability. EF 4/5 can't miss that important feature, right? I need some expert to help me with this question.

I happened to find a hack from this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server

However, it is more or less an 'undocumented magic' way, and it has some unknown limitations (Limitation link from that page has been removed, so I dunno what they are). So, it is not reliable enough for me to use it, and I won't be surprised if it suddenly doesn't work after a new EF patch. Is there a more 'offical' way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/), which enables caching via SqlDependency of arbitrary LINQ queries. When it comes to EF, it boils down whether the SQL query as created by EF conforms to the restrictions for Query Notifications. Last time I checked EF was gratuitously adding a subquery in the request and thus making the queries un-notifiable. I hear latest EF is better and it may work, but I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

.Net provides ways to invalidate the cache when you want, you could set up your your update page that the product manager uses to invalidate the cache when they do an update. Might be easier than setting up a service broker

Comment: Did you mean the page cache by time and param? If that was what you meant, I have mentioned it in the first paragraph. It's kind of a .net 1.0 thing. I want that smart update notification from broker service, like I can with a normal sql db + .net 2.0 web app...

Comment: I mean that you can invalidate the page cache when your update page gets used. This is how caching usually works. You don't have to wait to invalidate the cache after N seconds.

Comment: Hmm. It is likely the product manager pumps the data to sql db via ssis or something like that. He might not use the web app to update prices for a few thousand products. In that case, web app has no idea what is happening at sql db. Plus, we may have more than one app accessing the db...

Answer (score 1):

> it has some unknown limitations (Limitation link from that page has been removed, so I dunno what they are)

I've just fixed that broken link. It is nothing mysterious, just a link to the [MSDN article "Creating a Query for Notification"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28SQL.105%29.aspx).